# 2D Integral of $x_1x_2$ times gaussian over quarter plane

Tags: probability, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, normal-distribution

Came across the integral

$$\int_{x_1, x_2 > 0} x_1 x_2 dX$$

where $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma)$ is a 2D Gaussian. So we could write it as

$$= \int_{x_1, x_2 > 0} x_1x_2\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left( - \frac12 x^T\Sigma^{-1}x \right)\right)dx_1dx_2$$

The claim is that if $\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} a  & b \\ b & d\end{bmatrix}$, and we abbreviate $\theta := \cos^{-1}\left( \frac{b}{\sqrt{ad}} \right)$, then the answer is

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \sqrt{ad} (\sin \theta + (\pi - \theta) \cos \theta).$$

In the case that $\Sigma = I$, it works, because then we get

$$\int_{0}^\infty \int_0^\infty x_1x_2 \left(\frac{1}{2\pi} \exp\left(- \frac{1}{2}(x_1^2 + x_2^2)\right) \right) dx_1dx_2$$

$$= \frac{1}{2\pi} \cdot \left( \int_0^\infty x \exp\left( - \frac12 x^2 \right) \right)^2 = \frac{1}{2\pi}$$

which agrees when $\theta = \cos^{-1}(0) = \pi/2$.

I've been banging my head against the proof for a while with no success. Please help!

(I would link to the solution that I've found, but you don't want to see it. Everything is phrased totally differently, and it would be a slog to see the claim in the weeds. If you really want, it's [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.00165.pdf) on page 12, linking to [this](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/3628-kernel-methods-for-deep-learning.pdf) on page 2.)

Comment: Greetings, are you sure about the integral, because as it is now it seems unbounded, for some reason I was hoping something related to the distribution on the integral, sorry if it is stupid to ask

Comment: @keoxkeox It shouldn't be unbounded...take a look for $\Sigma = I$

Comment: I was seemed to be confused regarding the notation $dX$ I guess. I am looking for $E[x_1x_2 | x_1>0 , x_2>0]$

Comment: @keoxkeox I made it a bit clearer.

Comment: I will also try to do this with pen and paper but the general idea must be dealing with $((\sqrt{d}x_1 - \sqrt{a}x_2)^2+2\sqrt{ad}(1-\cos(\theta))x_1x_2)$ instead of $(dx_1^2 + ax_2^2-2bx_1x_2)$

Answer (score 3):

The general approach here is a change of variables.  We have using standard notation for the bivariate normal distribution

$$\Sigma = \pmatrix{\sigma_1^2 & \rho\sigma_1 \sigma_2 \\ \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2 & \sigma_2^2} \\  \Sigma^{-1} = \frac{1}{1 - \rho^2}\pmatrix{\sigma_1^{-2} & -\rho\sigma_1^{-1} \sigma_2^{-1} \\ -\rho \sigma_1^{-1} \sigma_2^{-1} & \sigma_2^{-2}},
$$

which translates to $\sigma_1 = \sqrt{a}$,  $\sigma_2 = \sqrt{d}$ and $\rho = b/\sqrt{ad}$.

Since $\Sigma^{-1}$ is a positive definite matrix, there is a lower triangular, nonsingular matrix $C$ such that

$$C'\Sigma^{-1}C = I \\ |C'||\Sigma^{-1}||C| = 1 \implies |C| = |\Sigma|^{1/2} \\ I = I^{-1} = (C'\Sigma^{-1}C)^{-1} =  C^{-1} \Sigma (C')^{-1} \implies CC' = \Sigma.$$

The actual form is

$$C = \pmatrix{ \sigma_1 & 0 \\ \rho \sigma_2  & \sigma_2\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}
$$

You are trying to find the off-diagonal component of

$$ K =\frac{|\Sigma|^{-1/2}}{2 \pi}\int_D \mathbb{x} \mathbb{x}'\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{x}'\Sigma^{-1}\mathbb{x}\right) \, d \mathbb{x},$$

where $D = [0,\infty) \times [0,\infty)$.

Make the change of variables $\mathbb{x} = C\mathbb{z}.$  The integral transforms to

$$K = \frac{|\Sigma|^{-1/2}}{2 \pi}C\int_{D'} \mathbb{z}' \mathbb{z}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{z}'\mathbb{z}\right) \, |C|d \mathbb{z}C' = C\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{D'} \mathbb{z}' \mathbb{z}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{z}'\mathbb{z}\right) \, d \mathbb{z}C'.$$

The integrand now factors into the form $f(z_1)g(z_2)$.  You just have to (1) determine how the region $D$ transforms to $D'$ under the change of variables, (2) carry out the integration of all four components, and (3) pre- and post-multiply by $C$ and the transpose $C'$.

In this case, we have $D' = \{(z_1,z_2) \, |\, 0 \leqslant z_1 < \infty, \, -(\rho/\sqrt{1- \rho^2})z_1 \leqslant z_2 < \infty \}$ and the problem reduces to computing the integrals

$$\int_0^ \infty e^{-z_1^2/2} \left(\int_{-\left(\rho/\sqrt{1- \rho^2}\right)z_1}^ \infty z_i \, z_j  e^{-z_2^2/2}\, dz_2\right) \, dz_1$$

for $i, j = 1, 2$.  Using polar coordinates we get integrals of the form

$$\int_0^\infty r^3 e^{-r^2/2} \, dr \int_{- \tan^{-1}\left(\rho / \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\right)}^{\pi/2}\cos^\alpha \theta \sin^\beta \theta \, d\theta$$

Comment: Have a look at page 8 of the link below, if you like. It seems the final execution of the integral requires some ingenuity. But the part you have provided is really what I wanted to know. (Sorry I didn't provide this earlier...I just understood the connection)

Comment: https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~saul/papers/nips09_kernel.pdf

Comment: Actually, in our case, their $n=1$, so probably it doesn't really need any of their fancy tricks.

Comment: I've never seen this way of writing a $2 \times 2$ positive definite matrix before. Is there a more general principle at work? Why define $\rho$ like that?

Comment: This is the standard notation for a bivariate normal distribution -- variances $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ and a correlation coefficient $\rho$.  The factorization $\Sigma = CC'$ is called the Cholesky decomposition.  I already knew the form so I used it rather than start with $a,b,d$.  I gave you the translation.  The integrals in terms of polar coordinates are relatively easy to compute in closed form.  The lower limit of the angular integral should correspond to $\cos^{-1}(b/\sqrt{ad})$.

Comment: If the integration is over $\mathbb{R}^2$ then the off-diagonal component of $K$ will be the covariance $\rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2$ as expected.  You are looking for the conditional covariance where the random variables lie in the first quadrant.